# Autorefresh excel file in sharepoint

Tags: microsoft-excel, sharepoint, refresh

I have an excel file that is connected to some external data sources (sql server...). This file is used as a data source in a power bi dashboard. What I want is to have the data in this excel updated without any human intervention or manually opening it. My initial plan was to have some kind of script refresh the file but since I am only allowed to use vba scripts I am stuck. I wrote a macro to refresh another excel file but still I have to have the first excel file always open in order to keep the macro running. My question is does sharepoint have such an option that allows me to set some kind of autorefresh for my excel file so it gets the latest data from sql server at specific intervals?

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint, there is a built-in way to refresh date in Excel.
Please refer to this thread to see if it helps:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ac97bc6f-3fc4-4af5-be6a-a139b0665e7d/auto-refresh-excel-file-in-sharepoint-library?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious